# How Does This List Assignment Work?

Tags: c#, xamarin

I have seen this code example and it looks like it assigns an array initializer to a List. I thought it would not work but somehow it compiles. Is {} not an array initializer? Children is of type IList. How does it work without the "new List" before the curly braces?

```
        var nameLayout = new StackLayout()
        {
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.StartAndExpand,
            Orientation = StackOrientation.Vertical,
            Children = { nameLabel, twitterLabel }
        };
```

Edit: When I tried `Children = new List<View>{ nameLabel, twitterLabel }`, the compiler gives this warning: "Property or indexer Layout.Children cannot be assigned to, it is read-only."

The code fragment is from Xamarin by the way: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/getting-started/introduction-to-xamarin-forms/

Comment: I just discovered this the other day as well, I haven't been able to isolate exactly how it works yet either.

Comment: According to the [MSDN docs on initializers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx) it appears that the compile calls `Add` repeatedly when using this initializer.  Note that you can't use this syntax directly in a variable declaration.  e.g. `IList<string> children = { "childfoo", "childbar"}` will not compile

Comment: @stephen.vakil: Sometimes, you kind of almost can.  `string[] children = { "childfoo", "childbar"};`

Answer (score 5):

There seems to be some confusion in the other two answers as to how this actually works. I refer you to the C# specification section on object initializers, which clearly summarizes the semantics:

> A member initializer that specifies a collection initializer after the equals sign is an initialization of an embedded collection. Instead of assigning a new collection to the field or property, the elements given in the initializer are added to the collection referenced by the field or property.

Remember, the specification is published for your convenience; if you have a question about the meaning of a C# language construct, it (or the printed annotated version "The C# Programming Language") should be your first reference.

Answer (score 3):

Not always. What you're thinking of is:

```
int[] array = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
```

That's the array initializer. However, you also have:

```
SomeObject obj = new SomeObject { Name = "Hi!", Text = "Some text!" };
```

This is an object initializer. What you have in your "replacement" broken code is another thing entirely - the collection initializer. This works with any type that implements `IEnumerable` and has an `Add` method with the proper arguments (in this case, something like `public void Add(View view)`).

```
SomeList list = new SomeList { "Hi!", "There!" };
```

In your case, the latter two are used, and the collection initializer doesn't instantiate a new collection. A simple sample code:

```
void Main()
{
  var some = new SomeObject { List = { "Hi!", "There!" } };

  some.List.Dump();
}

public class SomeObject
{
  public List<string> List { get; private set; }

  public SomeObject()
  {
    List = new List<string>();
  }
}
```

In this case, the code in `Main` translates roughly to this equivalent C# code:

```
var some = new SomeObject();
some.List.Add("Hi!");
some.List.Add("There!");
```

This form is only valid inside an object initializer, though - it's designed specifically for the case where you have a `readonly` field that you need to initialize using the object/collection initializer syntax. For example, this doesn't work:

```
var some = new SomeObject();
some.List = { "Hi!", "There!" };
```

If the compiler used the same "trick" as before, it could only add items to the collection - but it has no guarantee that the collection is empty (though even in the object initializer case, this is only a "guarantee by convention" - if you initialize the list with some items first, they will remain when the "assignment" happens).

That's all, folks :)

Comment: So as far as I understand, this is a special rule that applies only in the case of collection initialization inside object initialization. Is there any official documentation on this?

Comment: @JohnL. As far as I know, the last C# ECMA spec didn't have object initializers yet. I don't think there's any official documentation on this.

Comment: Of course there is official documentation on this; this feature was implemented *over ten years ago*.  See any published C# specification, or MSDN, or the dead-trees "The C# Programming Language", from the last ten years.

Comment: @EricLippert Well, the latest C# ECMA spec *is* ten years old. I couldn't find a mention of this in there. I couldn't find it on MSDN either. There's object initializers, collection initializers, array initializers... but I couldn't find anything about this special case. If you have a reference, I'd be happy to include it :)

Comment: There was no ECMA spec for C# 3, 4 or 5. The technical committee has reconvened and is working on getting caught up to the latest version.

Comment: The line of the spec you have been unable to locate is "A member initializer that specifies a collection initializer after the equals sign is an initialization of an embedded collection. Instead of assigning a new collection to the field or property, the elements given in the initializer are added to the collection referenced by the field or property. "

Comment: @EricLipper Great to know that it's a contractual behaviour, including the "not clearing up the collection beforehand" :)